# React-MobX Error: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean

Tags: reactjs, decorator, mobx-react

I get the following error: If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators'.

**package.json**

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": {
      "version": "7.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/-/plugin-proposal-decorators-7.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YooynBO6PmBgHvAd0fl5e5Tq/a0pEC6RqF62ouafme8FzdIVH41Mz/u1dn8fFVm4jzEJ+g/MsOxouwybJPuP8Q==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/helper-replace-supers": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/helper-split-export-declaration": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators": "^7.1.0"
      }
    },

 "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators": {
      "version": "7.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators/-/plugin-syntax-decorators-7.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-uQvRSbgQ0nQg3jsmIixXXDCgSpkBolJ9X7NYThMKCcjvE8dN2uWJUzTUNNAeuKOjARTd+wUQV0ztXpgunZYKzQ==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.0.0"
      }
    },

"babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": {
      "version": "6.13.0",
      "resolved": "http://registry.npmjs.org/babel-plugin-syntax-decorators/-/babel-plugin-syntax-decorators-6.13.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-MSVjtNvePMgGzuPkFszurd0RrAs=",
      "dev": true
    },
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": {
      "version": "1.3.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy/-/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy-1.3.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jYHwjzRXRelYQ1uGm353zNzf3QmtdCfvJbuYTZ4gKveK7M9H1fs3a5AKdY1JUDl0z97E30ukORW1dzhWvsabtA==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": "^6.1.18",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.2.0",
        "babel-template": "^6.3.0"
      }
    },
"requires": {
     "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.1.2",
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message says clearly what's wrong. It's unclear what tsconfig.json has to do with this. You wouldn't have this problem if Typescript were used to transpile decorators.

Comment: @estus I am using babel as a transpiler and not Typescript. Can you please provide a solution as per babel? Thank you!

Comment: The solution is to use legacy decorators. See https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy#babel--7x .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error message is a little bit confusing however with some little bit deep searching, you can resolve it using the following approach.

I make no assumptions, except that you are using webpack in this guide.

You need to add babel proposal decorators to your dev dependencies (You only need it during dev time) (which you have added already).

if using yarn

```
yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

otheriwse for npm

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

then in your package.json file, locate babel config section or add one if not there. The config name is strictly "babel".

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "legacy": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Pay extra attention to the indentation if typing it by hand. notice the object `"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"` is deeply nested inside two arrays, so it has to be as such to work.

and just for sanity check, your devDependencies would at a minimum be as

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2"
  }
```

Now you can build your application with either yarn or npm and live happily ever after.

Comment: @rlandster thanks for the solution. It's working like a charm now!

Comment: Typo in yarn and npm install commands:  bable, should be babel.

Comment: this worked perfectly, but please note you want to edit `package.json`, not `package.js` :)

Comment: @SlugFrisco thank you for picking that up, I've updated the answer to reflect the correct filename.

Answer (score 4):

React native 0.59

babel.config.js:

```
{ 
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}]
    ]
}
```

---

```
npm install @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save
```

---

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20588#issuecomment-448218111

Answer (score 1):

```
{
 "presets": ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
 "plugins": [
  ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "less" }],
  [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
    {
      "decoratorsBeforeExport":true
    }
  ]
 ]
}
```

Comment: this config in .babelrc successfully solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
"babel": {
   "presets": [
     "react-app"
   ],
  "plugins": [
  [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
    {
      "legacy": true
    }
  ],
  [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    {
      "loose": true
    }
   ]
  ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer are in the official document:
https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

you can find many ways to enable it in section "Enabling decorator syntax"

take the Babel 7 for example, create a project using mobx+create-react-app from scratch:

```
npx create-react-app hello-mobx

//This moves files around and makes your app’s configuration accessible.
npm run eject

npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

edit package.json:
package.json:

```
"babel": {
  "plugins":[
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy":true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose":true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "presets":[
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

install mobx:

```
npm install mobx --save
npm install mobx-react --save
```

enjoy!